# Can I upload to CloudFront directly from the browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Now that CloudFront [supports POST requests](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/10/15/amazon-cloudfront-now-supports-put-post-and-other-http-methods/), is it possible to do browser-based uploads directly to CloudFront?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, yes.  However, there are very serious issues with support for anything but the most simple upload requests from a browser.  For example, support for uploads to S3 via CloudFront using the multipart upload API is not possible due to the fact that CloudFront rips off the Authorization header from all of these requests.  Amazon appears to be unwilling to fix this issue.  This means you cannot support chunked requests from the browser if you target a CF endpoint or make any REST calls that require an Authorization header.

There is also an issue the prevents you from targeting differing CloudFront distribution endpoints (in order to more easily target different S3 from the same CF domain).

Comment: Confirmed. You just put the url of your CloudFront distribution in your POST request instead of the url of your S3 bucket. Fortunately I don't need chunked requests or authorization headers, so those weren't issues.

Comment: Hi @yndolok - could you update with your POST - I'm struggling to get it to work myself - how are you doing this?

Comment: @waxical Hi and sorry for the late reply. Here are a couple of articles I found helpful: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434, http://pjambet.github.io/blog/direct-upload-to-s3/. Do everything exactly the same as you would with a browser-based upload to S3, but use the url of your CloudFront distribution instead of your S3 bucket url.

Comment: It looks like the Authorization header is now preserved: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html

Comment: CF is a mess though. There are a number of issues when uploading to S3 via CF via the REST API. Some headers are still stripped. I ended up using a different CDN to deal with S3.

Comment: Uploading to Azure storage through Cloudfront via the Azure REST API works fine now when using SAS tokens.